# Google Turn Based Match custom Matches UI

Tags: java, android, google-play

I would like to provide a shortcut to each of the player's active matches on the main menu. The [Turn Based Multiplayer guide](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/turnbasedMultiplayer) goes into detail about how to use a custom UI for the player selection screen when first creating a match, but I am not seeing anything on doing the same for the default Matches UI.

Is it possible to get all of the active matches for the logged in player and display each of them as a shortcut to the match (essentially bypassing the default Matches UI)?

Comment: In the document you linked to, it mentions: "To start a match from the default player picker UI, call the `TurnBasedMultiplayerClient.getSelectOpponentsIntent()` method and use the intent it returns to start an activity". Are you wanting to have multiple instances of this intent? If so, it should be easy enough to create a list of these intents with the option to "Start a new match". Keep in mind you would need to maintain the state of all these different matches, which is also covered in that document under "Saving game state"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To list turn-based multiplayer matches, you can call following [method](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/turnbased/TurnBasedMultiplayer#loadMatchesByStatus(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20int,%20int[])).

If you want to list active matches, you can use MATCH_STATUS_ACTIVE and if you want to list matches where it is the logged player's turn you can use MATCH_TURN_STATUS_MY_TURN as argument.